# RESTEasy / Jettison, return Java object as JSON without the root node

Tags: json, backbone.js, resteasy, jettison

I'm using RESTEasy to return Java objects as JSON objects (which is using Jettison Mapped Convention for JSON marshelling).

But I don't want it to return the root node.

For example

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Car{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

An object of this class would result in JSON:

```
{"Car":{"id":6,"name":"someName"}}
```

Because it's actually coming from

```
<Car>
    <id>6</id>
    <name>someName</name>
</Car>
```

But I don't want the root node. I just want:

```
{"id":6,"name":"someName"}
```

So I can use it with client libraries likes Backbone.js

Is there any way (some annotation) to force this on the JSON marshelling ?

Sam,

Comment: Sam, did you find any answer for your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was faced with the exact same problem. After doing some research I found people suggested using resteasy-jackson-provider instead of jettison.
It was claimed that jettison has a few issues and that what you're experiencing is one of them. I switched to Jackson and found that it solved this issue and probably a few others that I wasn't aware of.
If you're using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

If you do this, you may see some collisions between jettison. To avoid those make sure you don't have the jettison jars on your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

You can define you Backbone.Mode like this:

```
var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {Car: {id: 0, name: 'bar'}};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a jettison related solution on the answer ["JAX-RS - JSON without root node in apache CXF"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20396007/1269441).

Jettison has a parameter called `dropRootElement` that does what the name says. In my case, the following addition of a `Configuration`-object did the job:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setDropRootElement(true);

new JettisonMappedXmlDriver(configuration)
    .createWriter(this.getOutputStream()));
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot when you need/want to stick up with the `JettisonMappedXmlDriver`!